# Getting a list of products in a category via join

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, entity-framework-core

I'm expecting to get a list of products using the query in this action method, and then map it to an `IEnumerable` of `ViewModelProduct` with AutoMapper:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<ViewModelProduct>> GetProductsAsync(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        var category = _context.ProductCategories.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (category != null)
        {
            var products = await (from c in _context.ProductsInCategories
                                  join p in _context.Products
                                  on c.ProductId equals p.Id
                                  where c.ProductCategoryId == category.Id
                                  select p).ToListAsync();
            var VMProducts = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ViewModelProduct>>(products);
            return VMProducts;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The models look like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public FrontPageProduct FrontPageProduct { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelFrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCategoryWithTitle> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping profile looks like this:

```
CreateMap<Product, ViewModelProduct>();
```

However, I get this message from AutoMapper:

> ProductInCategory -> ViewModelProduct (Destination member list)
>   MyStore.Models.ProductInCategory -> MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProduct (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>
> Title
>
> Info
>
> Price
>
> InFrontPages
>
> Categories
>
> AutoMapper.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable typeMaps)
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types:
>   List`1 -> IEnumerable`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyStore.Models.ProductInCategory, MyStore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProduct, MyStore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Am I missing a mapping, or is my query off?

Comment: The exception itself is because it's trying to map a list of ProductInCategory into a list of ViewModelProduct. Verify that the type of products is actually List<Product> when it gets to the mapping line. I have a reproduction of your error only when my source List is of type ProductInCategory. However, looking at the LINQ statement you provided, it appears like it should be returning the correct type, so I'm a little stumped why you're getting this error. Is there other code related to this? Is this the code exactly as it appears?

Comment: @ScottBaldric I will update my question to show the entire action method, not just the query and map-part.

Comment: I&#39;m not at a computer so I can't run code, but nothing is jumping out as the problem. For completeness, can you change the var to List&lt;Product&gt; ? It&#39;s also possible that your mapper is picking up data that mine didn&#39;t since I wasn&#39;t using fully hydrated objects. Is there a mapping set up for ViewModelFrontPageProduct and ViewModelCategoryWithTitle? The exception implies that the source list is wrong, but it could be on one of the nested models.

Comment: @ScottBaldric Yes! Changing `var` to `List<Product>` did it! :) Thanks! Post it as an answer, and I will accept it. :)

Comment: Awesome. Glad it's working! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is showing that it's trying to cast a list of `ProductInCategery` into the ViewModel instead of `Product`.

As mentioned in the comments, changing the `var` to `List<Product>` fixes the problem. Without seeing your exact setup, I can't know why the wrong type was being chosen, but this susses out the implicit casting problem.

Glad it got fixed! :)